# How can I store the integer in a character array?

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char ch[19];
    int c;
    cin >>c;
    ch[0]=c;
    ch[1]='\0';
    cout << ch;
}
```

what I want is to store the intger c at the location `ch[0]` but it stores the ascii value corresponding to that number like if.I put 97 then it stores a.
How can I put the character 9 in the character array ch?
Even if I typecast the variable c to char it doesn't help.

Comment: Isn't `sprintf(ch, "%d",c);` what you want?

Comment: You should probably read about [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: You're writing c++, use a `std::string` with @Someprogrammerdude's solution.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do that, better to use the type int for your array. As you should know, a char has a 1 byte size and an int 4 bytes size

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem, and you need to take a step back and think about (or ask about) what problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking questions about the method you're trying to use to solve it.

Comment: Side-note: [please remove the `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @Hurkyl according to a now-deleted comment from OP, this is actually not about reading numbers at all. +1 to you and VTC as unclear.

Comment: `cin` is a pain.  It has a lot of hidden flags you have to remember to use/configure.  I suggest using `getchar` inside a loop, such as `int n = -1; do { ch[++n] = getchar(); } while ((n <= 19) && (ch[n] != '\0xA'));`

Comment: Pressing "97" on the keyboard places two characters into the input stream, '9' and then '7'.  So, what you end up with in your character array is `ch[0] == '9'` and `ch[1] == '7'`.

Answer (score 1):

Standard streaming operators are overloaded on the type of their operands. By default, streaming into an `int` will read decimal digits, streaming into a `char` will read one character, streaming into a `std::string` will read a word, and so on.

So, if you want to read a single character (the digit `9`), just stream into a `char`, which you already have at hand:

```
std::cin >> ch[0];
```

Comment: actually I am supposed to store a count value in a character array

Comment: @bogor do you mean that if you enter `12345`, `ch` should contain `{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\0' }`?

Comment: @bogor I fail to see how this is in any way related to what your code snippet is doing. You have asked about reading digits, not letters...

Comment: I am was using this part in the program I haven't put up the whole question as it was not needed